# Custom filter not working in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, filter, django-rest-framework

I made a custom filter named Productfilter and imported it to my views. It was working until a few days ago but now has stopped working totally. I tried to pass the query parameters included in the filter, but all the objects are shown as if no query parameters are included in the API endpoint.

My view:

```
class ProductAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    # filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]    
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

My filter:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from ..models import *


class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   price = filters.RangeFilter()

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ['price','availability',
                       'warranty', 'services',
                'brand__id','category__id','collection__id']
```

My urls:

```
path('api/products', views.ProductAPIView.as_view(), name='api-products'),
```

My serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id',
            'category','brand','collection','featured',
            'best_seller','top_rated','name',
            'description','picture','price','size',
            'color','quantity','availability','warranty',
            'services',
        ]
        # lookup_field = "slug"
        depth = 1
```

Comment: You have commented out `filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]`. It is required for filters to work

Comment: Thanks,it worked. I thought I had given DjangoFilterBackend globally in settings.py..but when I looked at it, I see I had commented out. Anyway, thanks!